# How to do data protection for Azure Repos, restrict user in downloading as Zip file?

Tags: azure-devops, cloning, data-protection, azure-repos

I am trying to find a solution for restricting the users in downloading as zip or cloning option (or) basically to encrypt the source code in Azure Repos. Unable to find any docs related to it.

Comment: Look at the security settings if you need to restrict access.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, thanks for the immediate response. DO u mean Permission settings in Branch policies and in Project Settings -> Repositories -> Security ?    I have verified it we are not getting option for disabling the "Download as a ZIP" and disable clone option.

Comment: I doubt there are any options to disable "clone" or any other download if the people have access to your repo. What would that even help, if they still can copy the files one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanations in the following document, if the user could view your repo, he has the permissions to clone and download it at the same time:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#git

If you don't want the user clone or download the repo, you would also need to deny the user to access the repo:

[image]

Comment: HI @Cece Dong - MSFT/@James Z /@ Daniel Mann, Thanks for your suggestions. Have raised a ticket to Microsoft regarding the "Encryption of GIT Repo & other Azure Devops components. " . They have confirmed that "requirement is unsupported by design." . Thanks for the suggestions